# Confused about Light Locker/Power Manager settings in Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: xubuntu, power-management, screensaver

In Xubuntu 14.04, Light Locker and Power Manager settings are different control panel views, however, there are screensaver settings inside Light Locker's one. Anyway, there's no screensaver options to choose one from, so I deduce it just turns off my monitor.

I'm confused about it. Where should I configure when to turn off my monitor? Does Power Manager settings overrides Light Locker screensaver settings?

For example, the included Parole (media player) includes an option to deactivate screensaver when playing. Would Power Manager settings turn off my monitor anyway?

By the way, what does `Monitor power management control` inside 
`Energy settings -> General` mean?